# Read contents of a file from within Inno Setup installer

Tags: inno-setup, pascalscript

I am using Inno Setup. I read from file with

```pascal
LoadStringsFromFile(My_file, Lines)
```

but the file is outside installation file defined with

```
OutputBaseFilename={#MySetupExeName}
```

Can I open a file inside iss code, and this file to be in installation file (`OutputBaseFilename`)?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use [`ExtractTemporaryFile`](https://jrsoftware.org/ishelp/index.php?topic=isxfunc_extracttemporaryfile):

```pascal
[Files]
Source: myfile.txt; Flags: dontcopy
```

```pascal
[Code]
...
ExtractTemporaryFile('myfile.txt');
LoadStringsFromFile(ExpandConstant('{tmp}\myfile.txt'), Lines);
...
```

---

Though as the contents is fixed, you can as well hard-code it.

Or read it from the file on compile-time, instead of having to extract the file on install-time. You can use preprocessor [`FileRead` function](https://jrsoftware.org/ispphelp/index.php?topic=fileread) for that. Though it's more complicated than the straightforward code above. We would have to know more about that you need the contents for and how it looks like to offer an efficient solution.